# Option Value in loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I must first apologise, I'm self teaching python so any help is much appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/queens-park-rangers/startseite/verein/1039/saison_id/2015", headers={
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

playVal = soup.find_all("select", attrs={'data-placeholder':'Player(s)'})
print playVal
```

I would link to just return the 63632 `<option value="63632">GGGG<option>` so I can add on a loop to form a link

```
fullLink = 'http://www.test.com/' + playVAL['63632']
```

I hope this makes sense

Many Thanks

Comment: Are there multiple options in the select or just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to iterate over all of the `select`s you've found and then iterate over all of the `option`s within each of those to extract the values. Something like below should help you:

```
values = []
for select in playVal:
    for option in select.find_all('option'):
        values.append(option.get('value'))
print values
```

If you're a fan of list comprehensions:

```
values = [option.get('value') for select in playVal for option in select.find_all('option')]
```